# how to remove parts in url use htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have url :

```
http://localhost/project/home/index.php
```

I want remove /home/ in my url. How to do this?
My htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteRule ^home/(.+)$   $1/index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ home/index\.htm
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ home/index\.php
```

This should point your site.com/index.html and index.php to home/index.html and home/index.php respectively

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking to do?

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^/project/home/(.+)$   $1
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that you have it down 2 directories. Try that. The other answer is for the first directory.

Comment: sorry my bad ! i'm a newbie in htaccess i have tried but not success .

Comment: Actually the intention was quite the opposite. The actual files were in home directory. and Van wanted the root request /index.php to translate to /home/index.php